# Ignore TypeScript errors introduced by imported third-party packages

Tags: typescript

I want to import a TypeScript file contained in a package (`node_modules`). The external file contains type errors. When I run TypeScript compiler without importing the file, no errors are reported. However, I need the file for both its content and type declarations. Whenever I import the file, the errors contained in the file are also being reported when I run the compiler.

I've tried to `include` only my `src` folder, `exclude` the external file, make `compilerOptions.types` an empty array, set `compilerOptions.skipLibCheck` to true and/or put `//@ts-ignore` at my imported place, but none of these helps.

Considering that the file is in `node_modules` and I don't have access to that library, I cannot go into the file and fix the error or just write `//@ts-ignore` in it, because all changes will be overwritten in the future.

For example,

```js
//@ts-ignore
import IntersectSrc from 'vuetify/src/directives/intersect'

export function foo() {
    console.log("Hello World")
    IntersectSrc.inserted(document.createElement('div'), {})
}

export type InsertFunctionType = typeof IntersectSrc['inserted']
```

with the following `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/vuetify/src/directives/intersect/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

reports error `Property '_observe' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'` from `node_modules/vuetify/src/directives/intersect/index.ts`.

So my question is, are there any ways to ignore the errors introduced by importing third-party packages?

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: @jamesemanon I wasn't able to fix it eventually... The error appeared in WebStorm error dialog only and the build didn't fail so can I still live with it